# Get a Facebook Public Page Album with Graph JSON and produce HTML output via PHP USING ACCESS KEY

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to grab the graph feed of a (public) Fb page album in PHP, convert the JSON feed to html and output. I found this URL that seems to get me part way:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20src,created,caption%20from%20photo%20where%20album_object_id=391495207538675%20order%20by%20created%20desc%20limit%20100

I appreciate that there's a limit of 100 images, which is fine. What I'm struggling with is the access key. I understand that this is needed (although I can get the JSON of any public page album without it - not sure how that works). So:

1. Why do I need it (access token)? I assume so that my page/feed doesn't get blacklisted by FB?
2. How do I use the access token? I added "manage_pages" from "Get access token/Extended permissions". This gives me my Access token relating to my personal profile, right? I tried adding it in the URL above (i.e. ... where album_object_id=391495207538675 AND access_token=ABCDE) but I got: "(#602) access_token is not a member of the photo table."
3. How can I then best process this into some img's on page?

I've read a good number of items in S.O. about this but some seem out of date now when I follow the steps, others lost me part way through, some are a little advanced for my newbie skills, but help would be appreciated. Apologies if I sound like I'm getting confused here, but ... I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method below.

id=FACEBOOK USER ID & PHOTO ALBUL ID

```
$query = "SELECT aid,object_id,name,size,type FROM album WHERE owner = '$id' ORDER BY modified DESC";}
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.rawurlencode($query).'&format=json-strings';

            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $return_data = curl_exec($ch);
            $json_array = json_decode($return_data,true);

            return $json_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no-one had an answer here but I've found a good solution here: http://kevinp93.com/facebook-images-on-website-v2/ and it turns out that I just had the wrong order to the access token in the URL - it had to be at the end or it classed the rest of the URL as part of the token.

Comment: Then you just _build_ your URL wrong (most likely forgot proper URL encoding for some value) – the order of GET parameters in the URL does not matter.